# Formatação e apresentação de comentários no WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Tenho duas section no meu site, uma mostra os comentários e a outra é um formulário para os comentários:

Section `sec-aval` - Mostra comentário

```
  <section id="sec-aval">
     <aside class="sec-aval-asd first">
        <h1>Título do comentário</h1>
        <span class="autor">Autor do comentário</span>
        <p>Comentário</p>
     </aside>
  </section>
```

Section "sec-contato" - Pega o comentário

```
  <section id="sec-contato">
     <h1>Contato</h1>
     <p>Deixe sua mensagem, sugestão ou crítica</p>
     <form action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Seu nome">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Título da mensagem">
        <textarea cols="0" rows="0">Sua mensagem...</textarea>
        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
     </form>
  </section>
```

Como fazer esse sistema utilizando as funções php do WordPress?
Obs: Preciso que a section `sec-aval` mostre somente os últimos três comentários.

Answer (score 1):

Leia no [Codex do WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org) sobre as seguintes funções:

- Para listar: [`wp_list_comments`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments)
- Para carregar um arquivo com seu tema de comentários: [`comments_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template)
- Para customizar o conteúdo do formulário de envio de comentários: [`comment_form`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form)

Um bom exemplo de código pode ser tirado do tema padrão Twenty Fourteen: [Listagem de Comentários e inclusão do `comment_form`](http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/twentyfourteen/1.0/comments.php).